# How to handle ampersand in Java String and send a URL as a query parameter value?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to call a URL from Java code in the following way:

```
userId = "Ankur";
template = "HelloAnkur";
value= "ParamValue";
String urlString = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/notifications?template=" +
    template + "&href=processThis.jsp?param=" + value + "&access_token=abc123";
```

I have the following problems in this:

1. When I do `println(urlString)`, I see that the `urlString` only has the value upto and before the first ampersand (`&`). That is, it looks as: `https://graph.facebook.com/Ankur/notifications?template=HelloAnkur` and rest of it all (which should have been `&href=processThis.jsp?param=ParamValue&access_toke=abc123`) gets cut off. Why is that and how can I get and keep the full value in `urlString`? Does `&` needs to be escaped in a Java String, and if yes, how to do it?
2. Notice that I am trying to pass a (relative) URL as a parameter value in this query (the value of `href` as `processThis.jsp?param=ParamValue`. How can I pass this type of value of `href` without mixing it up with the query of this URL (`urlString`), which only has three parameters `template`, `href` and `access_token`? That is, how can I hide or escape `?` and `=`? Further, what would I need to do if `value` was `Param Value` (with a space)?
3. Notice that the `template` has the value `HelloAnkur` (with no space). But if I wanted it to have space, as in `Hello Ankur`, how would I do it? Should I write it as `Hello%20Ankur` or `Hello Ankur` would be fine?
4. I need the solution in such a way that `URL url = new URL(urlString)` can be created, or `url` can be created via `URI`. Please describe your answer up to this point as creating a safe URL is not straight forward in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Java, but there's this link that talks about URLEncoding in Java, which is what you need for your URI I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Comment: @dKen I tried this, it did not work for me. My first problem here is that the URL `String` gets truncated at the first `&`, and I don't know why. Your reference talks about encoding the query parameters' values. That is my later problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is going to become a classic)

Use URI Templates ([RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)). Using [this implementation](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) (disclaimer: mine), you can avoid all encoding problems altogether:

```
// Immutable, can be reused as many times as you wish
final URITemplate template = new URITemplate("https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}"
    + "/notifications?template={template}"
    + "&href=processThis.jsp?param={value}"
    + "&access_token=abc123");

final Map<String, VariableValue> vars = new HashMap<String, VariableValue>();

vars.put("userId", new ScalarValue("Ankur"));
vars.put("template", new ScalarValue("HelloAnkur"));
vars.put("value", new ScalarValue("ParamValue");

// Build the expanded string
final String expanded = template.expand(vars);

// Go with the string
```

Note that URI templates not only allow scalar values, but also arrays (the RFC calls these "lists" -- implemented as `ListValue` in the above) and maps (the RFC calls these "associative arrays" -- implemented as `MapValue` in the above).

Comment: How can I use your implementation -- will I have to import a package so that URITemplate can be recognized? Will I have to download something or can I copy-paste the code in some way in my project? BTW, I am using Eclipse and my code is deployed on Google App Engine. I would appreciate if you could provide directions. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use maven in your project?

Comment: I forgot: you can just download it from Maven central, see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/uri-template/0.3). Note: Guava is also needed as a dependency. Other jars (testng, jackson-coreutils) are only needed for tests

Comment: No, I don't use Maven or Guava. (I don't know what it is, and how it can be used with Eclipse and Google App Engine).

Comment: No need for maven especially. But you'll need to download Guava. Follow the links to it in the link above.

Comment: I saw the link. To understand you clearly, should I download the jar file from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/r09/guava-r09.jar? Where do I save this file after that -- in the war directory? What will I have to download to get your implementation? To get the class `URITemplate`, what will I need to import?

Comment: No, not r09, 14.0.1! As to my jar, you must also download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/fge/uri-template/0.3/uri-template-0.3.jar -- the fact that `r09` appears first is a bug in the site, `r09` is a _very_ early version of Guava.

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded both the files (Guava 14.0.1 and your jar file). Where do I save them?

Comment: (I figured out how to include the jars, they just needed to be included in the Java build path as external jars) The method `URITemplate template = new URITemplate("https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}"
    + "/notifications?template={template}"
    + "&href=processThis.jsp?param={value}"
    + "&access_token=abc123");` is throwing `URITemplateParseException`. Any idea what can be done about this?

Comment: Please tell the full error message: there must be the offset where it has failed, and the reason why

Comment: FWIW, the code in my answer compiles and runs fine (save for a missing parenthesis which I have added)

Comment: I got a message (`from getMessage()`) that no `suitable parser found (at offset 110)`.

Comment: Open an issue on github (https://github.com/fge/uri-template/issues), and please put the relevant code with the full stack trace

Comment: BTW, here is the actual code I have written: `template = new URITemplate("https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}"
       + "/notifications?template={template}"
       + "&href={href}"
       + "&access_token=12345601748147|hCLK3wsvBUMSafANub0HSFD0C9s");` Note that there is `|` character in `access_token`. Do you think this could cause problems?

Comment: Yes, it will cause problems! It is not a valid literal character in a URI. The message is therefore normal. Make that access token a variable (as the user ID, etc).

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem completely. It is working like a charm!

Comment: @Ankur you're welcome :) And in this "REST API" crazy age of ours, I surmise this library will be more and more used as time goes...

Comment: I am an infrequent programmer in Java, so I am surprised to discover that there is no easy and straight forward way of calling a URL in the language. Your API will have uses in many more situations.